# Multiple call to the Action while rendering twig page

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

I am designing a Shopping Cart.
This is my payment action in the controller.

```
public function paymentAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
        $userid=$securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
        $total = $em->getRepository('ShopperShopBundle:Item')->getTotal1($userid);//get total price

      // var_dump($total);exit;
        //update order table

        $order = new Order();
        $order->setUser1($em->getReference('ShopperShopBundle:User', $userid))
              ->setTprice($total[0][1])
              ->setStatus('Incomplete');

          //var_dump($order);exit;  

        $em->persist($order);

        //empty the cart
        $remove = $em->getRepository('ShopperShopBundle:Item')->findBy(array('user'=>$userid));
        if (!$remove) {
          throw $this->createNotFoundException(
              'Your Cart is empty. If you checked out recently and revisiting the cart, the items are lost. You can go to orders and complete your incomplete transaction. :-('
          );
        }

        $em->remove($remove[0]);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('ShopperShopBundle:Default:payment.html.twig',array('categories'=>0,'total'=>$total[0][1]));
    }
```

It inserts into Order table twice. But when I exit before returning, order is inserted only once.

These are my routes.

```
shopper_shop_checkout:
    pattern:  /checkout
    defaults: { _controller: ShopperShopBundle:Default:checkout }

shopper_shop_payment:
    pattern:  /payment
    defaults: { _controller: ShopperShopBundle:Default:payment }
```

If you need more information please ask in comments.
Problem occurs while rendering the page. Somehow, the insertion query is called again.

Comment: Please check your events listeners. Perhaps one call reinsert.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks buddy. It was the form action calling reinsert again. Please post that as answer.

Comment: without your controller/form-action added to the question this is never going to help anybody else :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the insert is not executed again in event listeners.